# What is the difference between "column" and "columnspan" in tkinter python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to set some buttons in tkinter, and I do not understand what is the difference between column and columnspan. Can anybody explain in a few words?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Column specifies which column you wish the widget to appear in

columnspan tells the layout manager that you wish for this widget to occupy more than 1 column i.e. spans across 2 columns

See <s>http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/grid.html</s> [https://users.tricity.wsu.edu/~bobl/cpts481/tkinter_nmt.pdf](https://users.tricity.wsu.edu/%7Ebobl/cpts481/tkinter_nmt.pdf) (New link to reference document)

For example

```
widget.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=3)
```

Will create a widget in row 0 and that spans across columns 1, 2 and 3

Comment: As of 2020/07/15, the link is broken.

Comment: @JSLavertu As of 2020/08/25, I've added a new reference link.

Answer (score 0):

**Column** and **Columnspan** are two properties of **grid()** method.

grid() method organizes widgets in a table-like structure in parents widget.

```
column = To put the widget in the specified column.

columnspan = To fix the columns widget will occupy.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll put in simple words:

it will make you button (or Entry field) occupy multiple columns.

```
mylabel = Label(window, text="Hi")
mylabel.grid(column=0, row=0)
```

In the previous code you can only put one widget under the label.

---

```
mylabel = Label(window, text="Hi")
mylabel.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=5)
```

whereas here: you can put 5 widgets under the label

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).